# Chernoff bounds - delta too large

Tags: probability, probability-theory, inequality, upper-lower-bounds

I am trying to solve some bounds with Chernoff bounds.

My problem is that the values i get for $\delta$ are usually so large that it is not possible to compute what is the result.

As an example here is my problem:

I start with

$ P(X \geq (1+ \delta) \mu) < \left(\frac{e^\delta}{(1+\delta)^{(1+\delta)}}\right)^\mu $

Now I want to solve the probability of $X \geq 30$ but my $\mu$ is so small that I need $\delta$ equal to 2000 to reach my inequality but solving the Chernoff bound with such a $\delta$ would be impossible.

Now the problem is that I only have this formula of Chernoff bound as the other requires $0 \leq \delta \leq 1$.

Is there any way I can dodge this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it is not impossible to approximate:

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=e%5E2000+%2F+%281%2B2000%29%5E%281%2B2000%29+decimal+expansion

However, the probability is just ridiculously small. Since that particular Chernoff bound is for a sum of $n$ i.i.d. Bernoulli r.v.'s with mean $p$ (so that $\mu = np$) it might be the case that $n < 30$, so that, in fact, $\mathbb{P}(X\geq30) = 0$ and you don't need the bound at all.

Comment: $n$ is > 30 the probability of success for every bernoulli random variable is just extremely small. Thanks for your answer!